# Setting default font for Shoes elements?

Tags: ruby, fonts, styles, shoes

I have the following code:

```
Shoes.app title: "Add a person to database" do  
  stack do

    title "Create a new person" 
    para "Enter their name:", :font => "MS UI Gothic"
        @name = edit_line
    para "Enter their age:", :font => "MS UI Gothic"
        @age = edit_line
    para "Enter their address:",:font => "MS UI Gothic"
        @address = edit_line
    para "Enter their mobile number:", :font => "MS UI Gothic"
        @mob_number = edit_line
    para "Enter their home number:", :font => "MS UI Gothic"
        @home_number = edit_line

    button "Add person to database" do
        Person.new(@name, @age, @address, @mob_number, @home_number)
        para newperson.details
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of setting the font style to be "MS UI Gothic" for each element, I wish to set the default font to be MS UI Gothic for all text that appears in the app. I cannot work out how to do this from any tutorials I have found. Any suggestions?

Comment: I could not find anything on global styles either in their documentation. Strange, I'd expect something like that to be present. At the very least you can use a variable `para_style = { font: "MS UI Gothic" }` and pass that to each para. At least that allows you to centralize the style definitions, and make changes in just 1 spot. Still a poor man's "solution", though.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you are using Shoes3 or Shoes4.

In Shoes3 you can just put `style Para, font: "MS UI Gothic"` anywhere in the `Shoes.app` block. And it will set that style for all the para's in the app.

```rb
Shoes.app title: "Add a person to database" do  
  style Para, font: "MS UI Gothic"
  stack do

    title "Create a new person" 
    para "Enter their name:"
    @name = edit_line
    para "Enter their age:"
    @age = edit_line
    para "Enter their address:"
    @address = edit_line
    para "Enter their mobile number:"
    @mob_number = edit_line
    para "Enter their home number:"
    @home_number = edit_line

    button "Add person to database" do
      Person.new(@name, @age, @address, @mob_number, @home_number)
      para newperson.details
    end
  end
end
```

Since Shoes4 is sitting in a new Ruby (1.9+) you would need to write 
`style Shoes::Para, font: "MS UI Gothic"` instead.

For more info about the differences between Shoes3 and 4 on this topic check out this conversation over on github: https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/pull/460.

Comment: Just FYI everyone, that the font support in Shoes 4 isn't all the way there yet.

Comment: I'm using Shoes 3.2, but I had to do `style Shoes::Para, font: "MS UI Gothic"` to set my fonts. I'm on Arch Linux x86_64.